# Why does Vim copy/paste between iTerm/Tmux windows work in Bash but not Zsh?

Tags: vim, zsh

I'm trying to switch from Bash to Zsh but have run into one major problem.  I can't copy and paste between Vim editing sessions when using zsh.  My typical way to edit multiple files is to open iTerm2 and Tmux, create two vertical Tmux panes, and then edit two files with Vim, one in each pane.  In a Bash environment, I can select text in one file/pane with "y" or I can yank lines with "yy" and then switch to the other pane/file and type "p" to paste the selected text or line.  With Zsh this doesn't seem to work at all whether I'm using Oh-My-Zsh or Prezto.  I've tested this scenario with a very minimal .vimrc file as shown below and with both of the minimal .zshrc configurations that are created when one uses OMZ or Prezto.  I know that Vim and these two shells handle buffers differently for security reasons, but I wouldn't think you'd have to know these internals to do something as basic as this.  I've read numerous articles on installing and configuring Zsh with both OMZ and Prezto, often within a Vim/iTerm2 environment, and none of them mention that any additional configuration is necessary.  I've also tried all of the usual remedies such as setting the iTerm2 preference that will allow applications in the terminal to access the clipboard and setting "clipboard=unnamed" in my .vimrc file.

```
# .vimrc
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set number
set hidden

# OMZ .zshrc
export ZSH="/Users/flaugher/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export TERM="xterm-256color"
bindkey -v
export KEYTIMEOUT=1
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit -I

# Prezto .zshrc
if [[ -s "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zpretzo/init.sh" ]]; then
    source "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprezto/init.sh"
fi
```

Why isn't Vim copy/paste working in Zsh?

Environment:
macOS 10.14.6
iTerm2 3.2.9
tmux 2.9a
Vim 8.1
zsh 5.7.1
GNU bash 3.2.57
OMZ & Prezto latest versions

Comment: I don't know how the shells involved would make a difference, because I'm not clear on how this kind of copying between two separate `vim` processes would work in the first place.

Comment: Why wouldnt you use one vim instance and `:vsplit` OR use tmux’s copy buffers ?

Answer (score 1):

After thinking through the problem, I realized that the root cause was that I was using the default version of Vim that comes installed on macOS Mohave.  This version doesn't have the clipboard feature enabled.

```
vim --version | grep "clipboard"     # -clipboard
```

I solved it by installing Vim using Home-brew.  And before I ran "brew install vim", I first edited Homebrew's Vim formula and added a line to the configuration parameters to ensure that the clipboard feature is compiled in:

```
brew edit vim
```

Add this line:

```
system "./configure", ...
...
"--enable-clipboard",
...
```

Then install but add the "-s" option so Homebrew compiles the formula from source:

```
brew install -s vim
```

After you do this, run vim --version again and look for `+clipboard`.

Also be sure to add this to your .vimrc file:

```
" yank to clipboard
if has("clipboard")
  set clipboard=unnamed " copy to the system clipboard
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yank the text into the clipboard buffer and paste from the clipboard buffer.**
How I would do it would be to yank with `"*y` and paste with `"*p`
It may be different depending on your setup. You need to also make sure you have +clipboard enabled in your vim.

For more info, check out [this link that explains in more detail](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim)

Comment: I realize this doesn't actually answer the question you asked, but I thought it would be useful to solve the problem you have.